# Is it possible to disable `requireUserAgentAndIpForSession` for specific instances?

Tags: plugin-development, security

I'm working on building a post-receive hook and a third party service's attempt to post data to a webhook keeps 302ing to the Craft login page when I attempt to use `EmailModel` and `sendEmail()`.

The only thing Craft logs during this failed transaction is a series of errors that read...

> Someone tried to restore a session from a cookie without presenting an IP address or userAgent string.

I noticed the `requireUserAgentAndIpForSession` setting in `UserSessionService->_checkVitals()`, disabled it, and of course the problem went away.

I'd prefer not to disable this setting in general—is there a way to programmatically unrequire it for a specific plugin receiving posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no... it's an all or nothing thing and you'll have to disable it globally.