# Is it possible to use Craft as a webservice when no useragent is sent?

Tags: plugin-development, slug

We're setting up craft as a webservice. One of my programmers came to me and said every "slug" he called from the frontend application resulted in a 302 redirect to the login page of craft CP. Afer some investigation it seems that he didnt sent any Useragent string from his frontend curl client. After adding a useragent string everything went ok. Is this normal behaviour or can it be configured?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This post may help:
[Is it possible to disable `requireUserAgentAndIpForSession` for specific instances?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/364/is-it-possible-to-disable-requireuseragentandipforsession-for-specific-instanc)

Take a look at the [`requireUserAgentAndIpForSession`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#requireUserAgentAndIpForSession) config-setting.

Post from phone, sorry if formatting is a bit off.